# Does Modelica Buildings Library work with Modelica.Media models?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a model that uses the Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa model to model a gas where the CO2 component becomes a majority constituent of the gas.

I would like to use the [Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory (LBL) Modelica Buildings Library](https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/) [three-way valve model](https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/releases/latest/help/Buildings_Fluid_Actuators_Valves.html#Buildings.Fluid.Actuators.Valves.ThreeWayLinear).  It appears to me that the Buildings Library only works with the Buildings.Media models and does not work with the Modelica.Media models.  After several hours of reading through the documentation, I have not found anything that says that the LBL Buildings library works or does not work with the Modelica.Media mediums.

Does the LBL Buildings library work with the Modelica.Media mediums?

Below is my test model and the error output from compiling with OpenModelica OMEdit Version 1.23.0-dev-6-g615dd08.

Thanks,
Michael

```
model SwitchedTest3WayBuildings "Investigate using Building library valves to model CDep 3-way valves"
  package MediumMixtureAir "Mixture Gas N2, O2, H2O, and CO2"
    extends MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa(mediumName = "AirMixtureGasNasa", data =
       {MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.N2, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.O2, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.H2O, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.CO2}, fluidConstants = {MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.N2, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.O2, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.H2O, MediaLowTempM4.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.CO2}, substanceNames = {"N2", "O2", "Water", "Carbon Dioxide"}, reference_X = {0.78, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01});
    //"Air created by using AirMixtureGasNasa Media model"
  end MediumMixtureAir;

  package Medium = MediumMixtureAir(reference_X = {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}, X_default = {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0});
  Real kg_per_sec_to_kg_per_day = 3600*24 "Multiply to convert kg/s to kg/day";
  type Pressure = Medium.AbsolutePressure(displayUnit = "Pa");
  type Temperature = Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature(displayUnit = "K");
  type MolarMassGr = Real(final unit = "g/mol", min = 0);
  type MassFlowRate = Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate;
  parameter Temperature T_Air_Ambient = 200 "Ambient air temperature and inital temperature";
  parameter Real h2o_inlet_ppm(displayUnit = "ppm") = 0 "Inlet concentration of H2O in ppm, baseline is  275 ppm";
  parameter Real co2_inlet_ppm(displayUnit = "ppm") = 2600 "Inlet concentration of CO2 in ppm, baseline is 2600 ppm";
  parameter Real p_system_psi(unit = "psi", min = 0) = 14.7 "System Pressure in psi";
  parameter Real FlowRateInSCFM(displayUnit = "SCFM") = 26.00 "Air inlet flow rate in SCFM";
  // https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/molecular-mass-air-d_679.html talks about the makeup of air.
  parameter Medium.MoleFraction moleFraction_n2 = 0.80 "Mole fraction of N2 in air, same as Volume %";
  parameter Medium.MoleFraction moleFraction_o2 = 1.0 - moleFraction_n2 - moleFraction_h2o - moleFraction_co2 "Mole fraction of O2 in air, same as Volume %";
  parameter Medium.MoleFraction moleFraction_h2o = h2o_inlet_ppm*1.0e-6 "Mole fraction of H2O in air, same as Volume %";
  parameter Medium.MoleFraction moleFraction_co2 = co2_inlet_ppm*1.0e-6 "Mole fraction of CO2 in air, same as Volume %";
  parameter MolarMassGr molarMass_n2_in_air = moleFraction_n2*molecular_weight_n2 "Molar Mass of N2 in air";
  parameter MolarMassGr molarMass_o2_in_air = moleFraction_o2*molecular_weight_o2 "Molar Mass of O2 in air";
  parameter MolarMassGr molarMass_h2o_in_air = moleFraction_h2o*molecular_weight_h2o "Molar Mass of H2O in air";
  parameter MolarMassGr molarMass_co2_in_air = moleFraction_co2*molecular_weight_co2 "Molar Mass of CO2 in air";
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_air = molarMass_n2_in_air + molarMass_o2_in_air + molarMass_h2o_in_air + molarMass_co2_in_air "Molecular weight of air";
  parameter Medium.MassFraction mass_fraction_n2_from_mole_fraction = molarMass_n2_in_air/molecular_weight_air "Mass fraction of N2 in air from mole fraction";
  parameter Medium.MassFraction mass_fraction_n2 = 1.0 - mass_fraction_o2 - mass_fraction_h2o - mass_fraction_co2 "Mass fraction of N2 in air";
  parameter Medium.MassFraction mass_fraction_o2 = molarMass_o2_in_air/molecular_weight_air "Mass fraction of O2 in air";
  parameter Medium.MassFraction mass_fraction_h2o = molarMass_h2o_in_air/molecular_weight_air "Mass fraction of H2O in air";
  parameter Medium.MassFraction mass_fraction_co2 = molarMass_co2_in_air/molecular_weight_air "Mass fraction of CO2 in air";
  // OneDrive "CryoCalc2 mjs v1.8 - Use OneDrive.xls" "H2O Flow" tab shows that 275 ppm H2O is an H2O concentration of 0.000171
  // 1 ppm water mass fraction is 1.5242e-6 gr/gr.  Inflow BC is 275 ppm.
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_n2 = 28.013 "Molecular weight of N2";
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_o2 = 31.999 "Molecular weight of O2";
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_h2o = 18.01528 "Molecular weight of water";
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_co2 = 44.010 "Molecular weight of CO2";
  parameter MolarMassGr molecular_weight_air_reference = 28.9664 "Reference Molecular weight of air";
  parameter Real X_shell_flow[4] = {mass_fraction_n2, mass_fraction_o2, mass_fraction_h2o, mass_fraction_co2};
  CoolerTypes.Cooler cooler = CoolerTypes.Deposition() "Cooler (coldfin, coldtip(s), and chamber)";
  final parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure SCFM_reference_p(displayUnit = "Pa") = 101325 "Reference pressure for SCFM conditions, 1 atm";
  final parameter Medium.Temperature SCFM_reference_T(displayUnit = "K") = 273.15 "Reference temperature for SCFM conditions, 0 C";
  final parameter Medium.MassFraction x_o2_for_scfm_density = 0.2638 "O2 Concentration needed to match that for dry air from the moist air media model";
  final parameter Medium.MassFraction x_n2_for_scfm_density = 1.0 - x_o2_for_scfm_density "N2 Concentration needed to match that for dry air from the moist air media model";
  final parameter Medium.MassFraction SCFM_reference_X[4] = {x_n2_for_scfm_density, x_o2_for_scfm_density, 0.0, 0.0} "Reference mass fraction for SCFM conditions, dry air";
  final parameter Medium.Density SCFM_density = Medium.density_pTX(SCFM_reference_p, SCFM_reference_T, SCFM_reference_X);
  final parameter Real cubic_feet_to_cubic_meters = (12.0*0.0254)^3 "conversion from ft^3 to m^3";
  final parameter Real SCFM_to_kg_per_second = cubic_feet_to_cubic_meters*SCFM_density/60.0 "Convert SCFM (1 atm and 0 C) to kg/s";
  parameter Medium.MassFlowRate SCFM_26_mass_flow_rate = 26.0*SCFM_to_kg_per_second "Flow rate for 26 SCFM in kg/s";
  parameter Real lower_limit = 0.001639;
  parameter MassFlowRate m_flow_start = 1.00*SCFM_26_mass_flow_rate "Was 0.012 Starting flow rate for tubes";
  parameter Pressure p_system = p_system_psi*6894.76 "System Pressure in Pa";
  parameter Pressure p_exit = p_system "Pressure at the exit of the simulation flow";
  output MassFlowRate m_flow_air_supply = -air_supply_pressure_boundary.ports[1].m_flow "Air flow into the deposition chamber";
  output MassFlowRate m_flow_c2_exit_pipe_in = co2_exit_pipe.port_a.m_flow "Air flow into the co2 exit pipe";
  output MassFlowRate m_flow_c2_exit_pipe_out = -co2_exit_pipe.port_b.m_flow "Air flow out of the co2 exit pipe";
  output MassFlowRate m_flow_cold_air_pipe_in = cold_air_pipe.port_a.m_flow "Air flow into the cold air exit pipe";
  output MassFlowRate m_flow_cold_air_pipe_out = -cold_air_pipe.port_b.m_flow "Air flow out of the cold air exit pipe";
  output Pressure p_co2_exit_pipe_inlet_gauge = co2_exit_pipe.port_a.p - p_system "Gauge pressure at the CO2 exit pipe inlet";
  output Pressure p_cold_air_pipe_inlet_gauge = cold_air_pipe.port_a.p - p_system "Gauge pressure at the cold air pipe inlet";
  output Pressure p_co2_exit_pipe_exit_gauge = co2_exit_pipe.port_b.p - p_system "Gauge pressure at the CO2 exit pipe exit";
  output Pressure p_cold_air_pipe_exit_gauge = cold_air_pipe.port_b.p - p_system "Gauge pressure at the cold air pipe exit";
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(T_ambient(displayUnit = "K") = 295, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, m_flow_small = 1e-02, m_flow_start = 0.014099, p_ambient(displayUnit = "Pa") = p_system, p_start(displayUnit = "Pa") = p_system) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-84, 82}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe cold_air_pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.1, height_ab = 0, length = 1, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b, p_a_start = p_system, p_b_start = p_system) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-36, -50}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe co2_exit_pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.1, height_ab = 0, length = 1, modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {58, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanPulse ValveControlSchedule(period = 2000, width = 80) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-54, -84}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary cold_exit(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 200, X = X_shell_flow, nPorts = 1, p = p_exit) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-62, -50}, extent = {{-6, -6}, {6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary co2_exit(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 200, X = X_shell_flow, nPorts = 1, p = p_exit) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {80, -50}, extent = {{6, -6}, {-6, 6}}, rotation = 0)));
  //Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToReal MassFlowRateInput(realFalse = 0, realTrue = m_flow_start)  annotation(
  //    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, -10}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT air_supply_pressure_boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = T_Air_Ambient, X = X_shell_flow, nPorts = 1, p = p_system + 5 + 20 + 5) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Fluid.Actuators.Valves.ThreeWayLinear threeWay_Buildings(m_flow_nominal = 0.0015, dpValve_nominal = 5, redeclare package Medium = Medium, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {42, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToReal booleanToReal annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {66, 38}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = -0)));
equation
  connect(cold_air_pipe.port_b, cold_exit.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-46, -50}, {-56, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(co2_exit_pipe.port_b, co2_exit.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{68, -50}, {74, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(air_supply_pressure_boundary.ports[1], threeWay_Buildings.port_2) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-70, 20}, {62, 20}, {62, 2}, {52, 2}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(cold_air_pipe.port_a, threeWay_Buildings.port_1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-26, -50}, {-14, -50}, {-14, 2}, {32, 2}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(co2_exit_pipe.port_a, threeWay_Buildings.port_3) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, -50}, {42, -50}, {42, -8}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(ValveControlSchedule.y, booleanToReal.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-42, -84}, {92, -84}, {92, 38}, {78, 38}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(booleanToReal.y, threeWay_Buildings.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{56, 38}, {42, 38}, {42, 14}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  annotation(
    Documentation(info = "<html>
       <body>  </body>  </html>"),
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 7000, Tolerance = 1e-08, Interval = 0.5),
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(cpu = "()", lv = "LOG_STATS", s = "dassl"),
    Diagram);
end SwitchedTest3WayBuildings;
```

Output from compiling with OpenModelica OMEdit Version 1.23.0-dev-6-g615dd08.

[4] 17:11:13 Symbolic Error
[/var/lib/jenkins2/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.23.0~dev-6-g615dd08/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/Differentiate.mo: 267:5-267:157]: Derivative of expression "threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.m = threeWay_Buildings.vol.V_nominal * CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.density(CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.ThermodynamicState(threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.medium.p, CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.T_hX(threeWay_Buildings.vol.ports[3].h_outflow, {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}, true, Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.ReferenceEnthalpy.ZeroAt0K, 0.0), {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}))" w.r.t. "time" is non-existent.

[5] 17:11:13 Translation Error
[Buildings.Fluid.Interfaces.ConservationEquation: 248:7-251:31]: Internal error
Differentiate.differentiateEquationTime failed for threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.m = threeWay_Buildings.vol.V_nominal * CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.density(CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.ThermodynamicState(threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.medium.p, CDep_library_v1.SwitchedTest3WayBuildings.threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.Medium.T_hX(threeWay_Buildings.vol.ports[3].h_outflow, {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}, true, Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.ReferenceEnthalpy.ZeroAt0K, 0.0), {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}))

[6] 17:11:13 Translation Error
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction1 failed! Use -d=bltdump to get more information.

[7] 17:11:13 Translation Error
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction failed!

[8] 17:11:13 Translation Error
Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't work with _all_ Modelica.Media models. Dymola gives a similar error: Failed to differentiate the equation
threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.m = threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.fluidVolume* threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.density_Unique174(
Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa.ThermodynamicState(
p = threeWay_Buildings.res1.port_b.p, 
T = smooth(2, threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.T_hX_Unique180( threeWay_Buildings.vol.dynBal.hOut, {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}, true, Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.ReferenceEnthalpy.ZeroAt0K, 0.0)), 
X = {0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0}
));

Comment: However, that error disappears for some other media.